# How to distinguish general people's names after screening proper nouns in NLP

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, spacy, wordnet

### Background

I would like to know how to distinguish general people's names after screening proper nouns in NLP.

```
preferred output
['Hanna', 'Mike', 'Cathy', 'Tom']
```

### Problem

I was able to extract proper nouns using nlp library, like spaCy, but

output

```
['Hawaii', 'Hanna', 'Mike', 'Barbacoa', 'Mexico', 'Cathy', 'Tom']
```

code

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

ppnouns = []

texts = [
"Mike, Tom, Cathy agreed; it was a magnificent evening.",

"Mike hopes that, when he's built up my savings, he'll be able to travel to Mexico to eat Barbacoa.",

"Of all the places to travel, Hawaii is at the top of Tom's list.",

"Would you like to travel with Hanna?"
]

#extract proper nouns
for i in range(len(texts)):
    text = texts[i]
    for word in nlp(text):
        if word.pos_ == 'PROPN':
            ppnouns.append(word.text)

print(list(set(ppnouns)))
```

texts are originally from the following webpage: https://examples.yourdictionary.com/reference/examples/examples-of-complete-sentences.html

I've edited the above sample sentences for my code.

### What I tried to do

Tried to figure out categories using a large lexical database of English, WordNet, but there was no return for peoples' names or different categories.

My current input and output are quite small but I'm planning to handle more big input, so I didn't create dictionary by myself like below.

```
dic = {'given_names'['Jack', 'Mike', 'Mary', 'Cathy', 'Tom', 'Jessica', 'Megan', 'Hanna'], 
'family_names':['Smith', 'Miller', 'Lopez', 'Williams', 'Johnson']}
```

How can I solve the issue? Is there any solutions or tools to realize what I would like to do?

[form - WordNet Search - 3.1](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=form)

```
#input
Hanna
#output
Your search did not return any results.

#input
Tom
#output
S: (n) tom, tomcat (male cat)
S: (n) turkey cock, gobbler, tom, tom turkey (male turkey)
```

### Development Environment

Python 3.8

Comment: having a database of either nouns that are not peoples names or the opposite is the way to go. Since names are nouns and many nouns can be names as well. There can be overlap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is to extract named entities with label "PERSON". With current `spacy` you can go as far as:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

texts = [
"Mike, Tom, Cathy agreed; it was a magnificent evening.",
"Mike hopes that, when he's built up my savings, he'll be able to travel to Mexico to eat Barbacoa.",
"Of all the places to travel, Hawaii is at the top of Tom's list.",
"Would you like to travel with Hanna?"
]

docs = nlp.pipe(texts)

names = []
for doc in docs:
    names.extend([ent for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_=="PERSON"])
print(names)
[Mike, Tom, Cathy, Mike, Tom]
```

Note, `Hanna` is missing from the list, meaning spacy's probabilistic language model won't recognize it as a name. If you want a deterministic model, it's better to define a dictionary of what you want to pick up.